# Reusable Bookmark in WorkFlow 4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Basically, I am using workflow to create a script template.

I create a new WorkFlowApplication. The Workflow then takes a script, asks the first question, creates a bookmark to wait for user input, and takes that input to determine the next question.

Is there a way for the user to change his mind on a previous question, and after he has resumed Bookmark#4 return to Bookmark#2 in the same workflow?

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Nobody's answered, and I don't have time to investigate, but can you take a snapshot of the workflow in the store on bookmark, save it off somewhere else and associated with that bookmark, and then reload *that version* when presented with a bookmark to resume from?  Might be difficult with the original implementation of the store, but it may be simpler with a custom version.  Of course, a custom version is VERY hard to create correctly in all aspects...

Comment: @Will That seems like a decent solution. The only problem being there are about 10-15 decision paths, on about 800 events a day, so thats a big active table being his by about 150 people.

Comment: Seems like a regular workflow isn't a good choice for you.  Have you looked into state machine workflows?  More complex to design, but you could support returning to previous states...

Comment: Ive been working with workflow for about 4-5 months and am just getting into it. It really is like an entirely different language. I will look into State Machine Workflows. Thank you.

Comment: @Will I know this is from a while back but maybe you will see this. What did you mean by `take a snapshot of the workflow in the store on bookmark`

Comment: When you bookmark, and the workflow gets saved to the store (database), copy everything saved to similar backup tables.  If you want to move back to a particular point, find the copy you want from these backup tables and overwrite what's currently in the store with the previous version.  It's doable, although I'd admit it would be a huge pain in the butt and is hacky as hell.

Comment: @Will do you have a few minutes to talk with me in a chat?

Comment: @Will Or is there a way to persist this store in memory instead of a table?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to ignore.  Am busy, which is why... You can create your own [InstanceStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.durableinstancing.instancestore(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation that keeps the workflow in-memory and saves previous versions.  Again, not an easy solution for your needs.